# Does anyone have a solution to this error in CKAN shown below?

Tags: solr, ckan

I believe I setup Solr properly(the solr admin page opens like normal).
The error is shown in the image provided.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yey2F.png

Comment: Its a 404, are you sure you are hitting the right endpoint where solr is hosted?

Comment: What URL have you used as the configuration value?

Comment: I checked over the configuration file jetty8 and this is what I have, I am also getting this error when trying to restart jetty8. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUKHU.png      https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUp5s.png

Comment: Copying-and-pasting the error messages is better than making screenshots, as the text can be searched.

Comment: Thanks will keep that in mind